# Django autocomplete_light shows placeholder but won't display choices

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm attempting to create a simple auto complete field in Django and using autocomplete_light as my solution.  I've studied this for a week to no avail. The field in question shows the placeholder, 'type some text to search in this autocomplete', but that's as far as it goes.  When something is typed, it acts no differently than a standard text field.

My Code:

autocomplete_light_registry.py

```
import autocomplete_light as al

class OsAutocomplete(al.AutocompleteListBase):
    choices = ['BEER', 'CHEESE', 'WATERMELON', 'APPLE', 'SOUP', 'CARROT']
al.register(OsAutocomplete)
```

forms.py

```
import autocomplete_light as al
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField, ModelForm, Form
from models import Tblcashactivityhistory

al.autodiscover()

class NewTransactionSetupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    local_currency = al.ChoiceField('OsAutocomplete')

    class Meta:
        model = Tblcashactivityhistory
        autocomplete_fields = ('local_currency')
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Tblcashactivityhistory(models.Model):
    transactionid = models.AutoField(
        db_column='TransactionID', 
        primary_key=True
    localcurrency = models.CharField(
        db_column='LocalCurrency', 
        max_length=255, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True
    ) 

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tblCashActivityHistory'
```

My html template has "{% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}" at the top.

Please help as I repeatedly read that django autocomplete_light is the popular solution.

Comment: Isn't there any JS error logged ? Are you sure jquery is not loaded twice ?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when jquery is loaded again after DAL's static files, which un-registers plugins.

Also, check that there is no JS or HTTP error in the console.

Comment: There is no error in the console of any kind.  How do i know if jquery is loaded more than once?

Comment: Use the network tab of webkit inspector and the HTML source.